# Why i get this error while installing graphics file and how can solve it?

Tags: command-line, graphics, c++, programming, syslinux

```
*** The sdl-config script installed by SDL could not be found
*** If SDL was installed in PREFIX, make sure PREFIX/bin is in
*** your path, or set the SDL_CONFIG environment variable to the
*** full path to sdl-config.
configure: error: *** SDL version 1.2.0 not found!
```

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Did you install the appropriate libsdl development package?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install [development package for the SDL library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=sdl-config) by:

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
```

and then resume the compilation process.