# After compiling and installing SDL, something happened to OpenGL and Vulkan

Tags: compiling, opengl, c, vulkan, sdl

I tried to compile and install SDL2 from https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation. Then I tried to test a program, I got a program file missing error for libsdl2-2.0.so.0: Program file cannot be opened. Pretty normal. Google time! I did some stuff from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711336/libsdl2-2-0-so-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file. I was trying to fix my problem.

I suddenly got a can't find -lvulkan error from gcc(I was still trying to fix my program file errors). I forgot what I had just done, in my attempts to solve the libsdl2-2.0.so program file error. For now, I removed the -lvulkan, it still didn't work due to the .so file not being found.

Then I ran `ldconfig` in the terminal, it was a simple solve, then it was running, I have no idea what that does, found I need to do it from Google. SDL worked, but -lvulkan error persisted. `SDL_CreateWindow()` wasn't working now. It was giving no available video device error. It's probably because of OpenGL stuff from my Google research. You know what? Now, -lGL too doesn't work. No linking against OpenGL after doing whatever I did, probably caused by the same thing that caused Vulkan problems.

Any idea what I might have done? Why is this happening? I only ran a sudo command once for `ldconfig`, how can any other thing do anything at `/usr`? I did got problems with the trash in nautilus, seemed like it thought that deleted files still existed. It was fixed after a restart. I had used nautilus with sudo once, that's where it could have gone wrong but my trash was empty, so I surely didn't delete anything.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1280826/66509

Comment: @N0rbert The repository was outdated and the problem has already arose.

Comment: Which exactly repository? What is your Ubuntu version?